# Accessor of array elements in C# error

Tags: c#, arrays, accessor

I have two arrays in my class and try to access them in the following way. The first one works for theta but the second failed to compile for delta_theta. What's the correct way of doing the second array without using this?

The error says: Error   1   Bad array declarator: To declare a managed array the rank specifier precedes the variable's identifier. To declare a fixed size buffer field, use the fixed keyword before the field type.

```
protected double[] theta = null;
protected double[] delta_theta = null;
public double this[int index] {
        get { return theta[index]; }
        set { theta[index] = value; }
}
public double Delta_Theta[int index]
{
        get { return delta_theta[index]; }
        set { delta_theta[index] = value; }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide us what error the compiler throws?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't specify a name for an indexer in plain C# code, nor can you create several indexers with the same parameter types and distinguish them by name.

You can specify a name for *other* languages (which support named indexers) to use via [`DefaultMemberAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.defaultmemberattribute.defaultmemberattribute.aspx) but you can't use the name yourself. (Other than for COM components, and then only in C# 4 and upwards.)

Instead, you'd have to expose a property of some type which *itself* exposes the relevant indexer. Now if you want get and set, you could just expose the array as a read-only property, possibly as an `IList<double>`:

```
// Names changed to be more conventional
public IList<double> DeltaTheta
{
    get { return deltaTheta; }
}
```

Then clients can still use:

```
foo.DeltaTheta[10] = 5.5;
```

for example.

For a read-only version, you could expose `ReadOnlyCollection<double>`:

```
public ReadOnlyCollection<double> DeltaTheta
{
    get { return new ReadOnlyCollection<double>(deltaTheta); }
}
```

or to avoid doing this every time, you could have a field for the wrapper: initialize it in the constructor, and then return the same wrapper reference every time.

Comment: What would then be the correct way to set and get the value for each individual element in delta_theta?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do that in the same class - indexer must be in form `this(arguments)` so you can't have 2 that use the same type of index.

What you can do is create inner class for sole purpose to redirect indexing to your array and make `Delta_Theta` return this class.

```
public IndexRedirector Delta_Theta 
{ 
  get { return new IndexRedirector { RedirectedArray:delta_theta }; 
}

class IndexRedirector
{ 
  public double[] RedirectedArray;
  public double this[int index] {
    get { return RedirectedArray[index]; }
    set { RedirectedArray[index] = value; }
  }
}
```

Comment: Is the new feature in .net 4? Compiler is reporting error on Array:delta_theta

Comment: @Yang, no... just bad choice of name on my side - updated... still not tried to compile... And you have the answer from the Jon - so safe to ignore this one :).

Answer (score 1):

You can create a wrapper indexer:

```
protected double[] theta = null;
protected double[] delta_theta = null;

public double this[int index] {
        get { return theta[index]; }
        set { theta[index] = value; }
}

public Indexer DeltaTheta { 
      // can be optimized according to delta_theta lifecycle
      get {return new Indexer(delta_theta);} 
}

// internal indexere wrapper
public class Indexer{
      double [] _data;
      public DoubleIndexer(double[] data ){   
          _data = data;
      }

      public double this[int index] {
            get { return _data[index]; }
            set { _data[index] = value; }
      }
}
```

and use like this:

```
obj[2]               // -> theta[2]
obj.DeltaTheta[5]    // -> delta_theta[5]
```